# Why does my electron app doesn't launch after packaging?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have problem with project(https://github.com/Gordienko-RU/plant-log), there are angular bundle in dist folder and electron main file into electron folder, but after packaging with electron-builder, application doesn't run. 
I guess there are some problems with my config in to package.json

Comment: Are some of your dependencies native addons (e. g. xxxx.node)?

Comment: As I see, there are not some native addons here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had a similar issue with electron-packager. I tried your package.json and did a "npm install". To me it looks like that your build does include native addons (*.node).

In electron-packager the solution was to add the asar unpack option. You are using electron-builder. Therefore you should look at this thread: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/390 . Maybe you need to specify the modules by hand, like:

```
  "asar": true,
  "asarUnpack": [
    "../node_modules/uws"
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you, will try to investigate this, or maybe change builder to electron-packager.